# Changing the value of jQuery's $(this) object inside an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, this

I'm wanting to click an image (`img#first`) and have it split into three smaller versions of another image (`img.cat`). Each time `img.cat` is clicked, it throws the cloned elements in random directions and temporarily shows a lion in place of the `img.cat` that was clicked.

The cat replication and lion popup both work properly (as you can see by clicking the smaller cat in the upper left corner), but I don't know how to make it so a .click() event on `img#first` will call the function to replicate smaller cats. To reiterate, I want the `img#first` to spawn 3 smaller `img.cat`, then disappear, then if the user continues to click new `img.cat` objects they continue to spawn more of themselves. The problem is just getting that original `img#first` to start the chain reaction and then disappear forever.

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7yu8/14/).

If I'm able to just make the entire `.click(explode)` function work on `img#first` and then swap that identifier somehow to `img.cat` after the initial click, wouldn't that do the trick?

For example:

```
var firstRun = 0
$('img#first').click(function() {
    if (!firstRun) {
        //do original stuff here
        firstRun = 1;
    } else {
        $(this) = $('img.cat');
        //do img.cat stuff here
    }
});
```

Or do I need to isolate the explode function so that it can be called separately on two different objects while achieving the same effect?

I honestly have no idea how to go about accomplishing either of these tasks. Maybe there's a simpler way to get what I want.

Comment: Your fiddle seems to work for me.  I click the `img#first` and 3 smaller cats are spawned, it turns to a lion, and the lion disappears.  I can continue to click on the smaller `img.cat` and the same sequence of events happen.  What am I missing?

Comment: You can't reassign the value of `this` in Javascript like you can a variable, and therefore can't change what `$(this)` represents in jQuery. One a side note: `$('#first')` is a more optimal selector than `$('img#first')`.

Comment: @SamSullivan You're clicking on the img.cat. Clicking img#first does nothing. I want it to start the whole process (with img.cat hidden initially). Basically, take the entire functionality behind the img.cat clicking and apply that to a different first image, then resume as normal.

Comment: @winterblood Thanks for the heads up RE: selectors. I'll look into the logic behind that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a separate event which triggers only on clicking `#first` which programmatically triggers a click on `img.cat` then removes itself like this:

```
$('#first').click(function() {
    $("img.cat").trigger("click");
    $(this).remove();
});
```

[Here is a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7yu8/16/).

Comment: That's precisely the functionality I was seeking. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 1):

Update your `$('img.cat').click()` event listener's selector to `$('img.cat, img#first)` to select **both** `img.cat` and `img#first`.  With this new event listener, you can remove your first `$('img#first').click()` listener.  See my updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7yu8/15/).

Comment: Close, but that just creates two different sets of cats. I only want the img#first to be clickable once, then gone forever. This was the first thing I tried. :D Thank you though and I truly appreciate your help.